# Passing a source with ExceptT to a sink

Tags: haskell, conduit

Given a conduit source with following type signature:

```
sourceMsg :: MonadIO m => ExceptT Err (ConduitM () ByteString m) ()
```

how can it be passed to [`Data.Conduit.List.mapM_`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.6.6/docs/Data-Conduit-List.html#g:4)? Something like below won't work because output is of type `ConduitM a o m ()`, not `ConduitM a o m (Either Err ())`.

```
> :t  ($$) (runExceptT $ sourceMsg undefined) (mapM_ undefined)
<interactive>:1:7: Warning:
    Couldn't match type ‘Either Err ()’ with ‘()’
    Expected type: Source m ByteString
      Actual type: ConduitM () ByteString m (Either Err ())
    In the first argument of ‘($$)’, namely
      ‘(runExceptT $ sourceMsg undefined)’
    In the expression:
      ($$) (runExceptT $ sourceMsg undefined) (mapM_ undefined)
```

I will just like to print the length of bytestring within `mapM_`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your sink conduit segment is `C.mapM_ BS.putStrLn`.

The first step is to unwrap the ExceptT value and compare it to the sink segment:

```
runExceptT sourceMsg :: ConduitM () ByteString IO (Either Err ())
C.mapM_ BS.putStrLn  :: ConduitM ByteString a  IO ()
```

When you using the Conduit fusing operators you have to choose which segment will return the value of the fused expression. The two main choices are:

```
a =$= b                -- b returns the value
a `fuseUpstream` b     -- a returns the value
```

Since we want to see the `Either Err ()` value, we'll use `fuseUpstream`:

```
let f = (runExceptT sourceMsg) `fuseUpstream` (C.mapM_ BS.putStrLn)
    :: ConduitM () c IO (Either Err ())
```

(Another requirement of fusing two segments together is that the segment *not* returning the value must return `()`. In our case this is already satisfied by `C.mapM_ ...`, but in general it is something to check. A segment may always be modified to return `()` by fmapping it with `const ()`)

The next step is to run the fused segments to yield an IO-action:

```
runConduit f :: IO (Either Err ())
```

and now we can tell if we got an error or not. The full solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.Except
import Data.Conduit as C
import Data.Conduit.List as C
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as BS
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Control.Monad

type Err = (Int, String)

sourceMsg :: ExceptT Err (ConduitM () ByteString IO) ()
sourceMsg = undefined

runSource = do
  do r <- runConduit $ (runExceptT sourceMsg) `fuseUpstream` (C.mapM_ BS.putStrLn)
     case r of
       Left _ -> putStrLn "error"
       Right _ -> putStrLn "no error"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @ErickR. Very helpful.